Producing image depicting number of days to value > 0 at each pixel in an ImageCollection with daily values of NDVI for North America
New to GEE but excited to learn more about it. I have produced NDVI values from the 'LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2' ImageCollection including every available day in 2022. I fitted a harmonic regression to these values to estimate the missing (daily) values at every pixel within North America. I am now interested in producing an image where the value for any given pixel is simply the number of days it took at that site for NDVI to become greater than 0 as the year progressed. I have not been able to figure out how to find out the different dates for each pixel and combine them into a single image. I am attaching my latest attempt to do this (but it clearly does not accomplish what I want to do).
///////////////////// CODE /////////////////////////////
var startdate = '2022-01-01'
var enddate = '2022-12-31'

// define region of interest
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon({
  coords: [[[-50, 10], [-180, 10], 
            [-180, 85], [-50, 85], 
            [-50, 100]]],
  geodesic: false
});

// Define function to mask clouds, scale, and add variables
// (NDVI, time and a constant) to Landsat 8 imagery.
function maskScaleAndAddVariable(image){
   // Bit 0 - Fill
   // Bit 1 - Dilated Cloud
   // Bit 2 - Cirrus
   // Bit 3 - Cloud
   // Bit 4 - Cloud Shadow
   var qaMask=image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111',
       2)).eq(0);
   var saturationMask=image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);

   // Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
   var opticalBands=image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-
       0.2);
   var thermalBands=image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802)
       .add(149.0);

   // Replace the original bands with the scaled ones and apply the masks.
   var img=image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
       .addBands(thermalBands, null, true)
       .updateMask(qaMask)
       .updateMask(saturationMask);
   var imgScaled=image.addBands(img, null, true);

   // Now we start to add variables of interest.
   // Compute time in fractional years since the epoch.
   var date=ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
   var JulianDate=date.difference(ee.Date(startdate), 'year');
   // Return the image with the added bands.
   return imgScaled
       // Add an NDVI band.
       .addBands(imgScaled.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B4'])
           .rename('NDVI'))
       // Add a time band.
       .addBands(ee.Image(JulianDate).rename('t'))
       .float()
       // Add a constant band.
       .addBands(ee.Image.constant(1));
}

// Import the USGS Landsat 8 Level 2, Collection 2, Tier 1 image collection),
// filter, mask clouds, scale, and add variables.
var landsat8sr=ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
   .filterBounds(polygon)
   .filterDate(startdate, enddate)
   .map(maskScaleAndAddVariable);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// fit harmonic regression to the observed NDVI data

// Name of the dependent variable.
var dependent=ee.String('NDVI');

// Use these independent variables in the harmonic regression.
var harmonicIndependents=ee.List(['constant', 't', 'cos', 'sin']);

// Add harmonic terms as new image bands.
var harmonicLandsat=landsat8sr.map(function(image){
   var timeRadians=image.select('t').multiply(2 * Math.PI);
   return image
       .addBands(timeRadians.cos().rename('cos'))
       .addBands(timeRadians.sin().rename('sin'));
});

// Fit the model.
var harmonicTrend=harmonicLandsat
   .select(harmonicIndependents.add(dependent))
   // The output of this reducer is a 4x1 array image.
   .reduce(ee.Reducer.linearRegression(harmonicIndependents.length(),
       1));
       
// Turn the array image into a multi-band image of coefficients.
var harmonicTrendCoefficients=harmonicTrend.select('coefficients')
   .arrayProject([0])
   .arrayFlatten([harmonicIndependents]);
   
// Compute fitted values.

// Apply the coefficients obtained from linear regression to each pixel's time series
var fittedHarmonic = harmonicLandsat.map(function(image) {
  // Multiply the harmonic coefficients with the independent variables (time, cosine, sine)
  var fittedValues = image.select(harmonicIndependents)
    .multiply(harmonicTrendCoefficients)
    .reduce('sum')
    .rename('fitted');
  
  // Add the fitted values as a new band to the image
  return image.addBands(fittedValues);
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Here I am trying to figure out the first day in which NDVI > 0 for each pixel

// Define a function to find the first unmasked NDVI value for each pixel
var findFirstValidNDVI = function(image) {
  var fittedBand = image.select('fitted');

  // Create a binary mask where 'fitted' is greater than or equal to 0
  var validMask = fittedBand.gt(0);
  
  // Use reduceRegion to find the first valid NDVI value for each pixel
  var firstValidIndex = validMask.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
    geometry: polygon,
    scale: 30, // adjust scale as needed
    bestEffort: true
  });
  
  // Return an image with the index of the first valid NDVI value
  return ee.Image.constant(firstValidIndex.get('fitted')).rename('first_valid_ndvi');
};

// Apply the reducer to your Image Collection
var firstNDVI = fittedHarmonic.map(findFirstValidNDVI);

// Calculate the number of days since the beginning of the year for each image
var dayOfYear = firstNDVI.map(function(image) {
  var doy = ee.Image(ee.Date(image.get("system:time_start")).getRelative("day", "year")).add(1);
  return doy;
});

// Combine the images in the collection into one image using mosaic or reduce with max reducer
var dayOfYearImage = dayOfYear.max(); // Or use .mosaic()

// Subtract the day of the year of the first unmasked NDVI value from each image
var daysSinceFirstValidNDVI = dayOfYearImage.subtract(1); // Subtract 1 to account for 0-based indexing

// Create a single image from the collection representing the number of days since the first unmasked NDVI value
var daysSinceFirstImage = daysSinceFirstValidNDVI.max(); // Use 'max()' to merge all images into one

// Display the result
Map.addLayer(daysSinceFirstImage, {min: 0, max: 50, palette: ['purple', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']}, 'Days since first valid NDVI');

// Center the map on the polygon of interest
Map.centerObject(polygon, 3);



https://medium.com/google-earth/runs-with-arrays-400de937510a

You can simply mask all the pixel values in your images that have NDVI values <= 0 and then apply a minimum reducer to the collection and extract the minimum date image. Here's a solution that makes minimal changes to your code.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Here I am trying to figure out the first day in which NDVI > 0 for each pixel
// Changes start in this section
// Define a function to add new band that adds Julian Date as another band
// and mask all NDVI values <=0 on all bands.
var maskNDVI = function(image) {
  var fittedBand = image.select('fitted');

  // Create a binary mask where 'fitted' is greater than to 0
  var validMask = fittedBand.gt(0);
  // Create julianDate band
  var julianDate = ee.Image.constant(ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'))
                                                  .difference(ee.Date(startdate), 'day'))
                                                  .rename('julianDate')
                                                  .float();
  
  // Return an image with the julianDate band and masked with the new NDVI mask
  return image.addBands(julianDate)
              .updateMask(validMask);
};

// Apply the reducer to your Image Collection
// reduce the collection to get the smallest value by pixel for the julian Date band. 
//Finally, you might want to round the values the lowest integer.
var firstNDVI = fittedHarmonic.map(maskNDVI)
                              .select('julianDate')
                              .min()
                              .floor()
                              .int();
print('firstNDVI',firstNDVI);
Map.addLayer(firstNDVI, {}, 'first');

